# Newtonsoft Object serialized to String. JObject instance expected

Tags: c#, json

Hi so am trying to parse this JSON line but i got some others that are like this in files thats why i want to automate this so i can remove the invalid lines to make the file a valid JSON for reading, The problem is that the JSON contains multiple JSON in 1 line

Example:

```
{"item":"value"}{"anotheritem":"value"}
```

Is there anyway to remove

```
{"anotheritem":"value"}
```

So it turns in to a valid JSON that is readable to start parsing the files

I tried doing using StreamReader cause there in a file i have multiple files that contain these invalid JSON

So i got it to be able to detect the Invalid JSON but for some reason i can't get it to read the JSON so i can use .remove to remove the invalid line

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(itemDir))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    if (json.Contains("anotheritem"))
    {
        JObject NoGood = JObject.FromObject(json);
        MessageBox.Show(NoGood.ToString());
    }
}
```

The Error:

```
Object serialized to String. JObject instance expected.
```

Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: Your json seems to be just one big line, could you narrow down what is problematic with it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen There are two distinct objects, without an array-wrapper or separator.

Comment: Made it smaller than it was by removing the items data it will now show the problem more clear thanks.

Comment: Then it isn't JSON, you should complain to whoever made the "json" content in the first place.

Comment: Ah ye good idea edited the question.

Comment: well it isn't a proper looking json... did you try to turn it into a string and then split it by '}{' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If each object are side by side without space or any other character, you can convert your string to an json array.

```
string value = "{\"item\":\"value\"}{\"anotheritem\":\"value\"}";
string arrayValue = "[" + value.Replace("}{", "},{") + "]";
var array = JArray.Parse(arrayValue);
var goopArray = array.OfType<JObject>().Where(o => o.Property("anotheritem") == null);
```

**Edit** : see my second answer. More robust solution. More modern. And support dotnet core builtin json serializer.

Comment: Awesome idea but var array = JArray.Parse(value); is var array = JArray.Parse(arrrayValue); Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

### Json.Net

Even better solution, Json.NET have a builtin feature for this exact scenario. See [Read Multiple Fragments With JsonReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm)

The `JsonTextReader` have a property `SupportMultipleContent` that allow to read consecutive items when set to true

```
string value = "{\"item\":\"value\"}{\"anotheritem\":\"value\"}";

var reader = new JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(value));
reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

var list = new List<JObject>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var item = JObject.Load(reader);
    list.Add(item);
}
```

### System.Text.Json

If you want to use `System.Text.Json`, it's also acheivable. They are no `SupportMultipleContent` property but `Utf8JsonReader` will do the job for you.

```
string value = "{\"item\":\"value\"}{\"anotheritem\":\"value\"}";

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value).AsSpan();

var list = new List<JsonDocument>();
while (bytes.Length != 0)
{
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(bytes);

    var item = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
    list.Add(item);
    
    bytes = bytes.Slice((int) reader.BytesConsumed);
}
```